# C programming structure initialization

Tags: c, struct

Say I define the following structure and have the following code:

```
struct PVS{
    int* values; 
}; 

struct PVS** pvs = (struct PVS**) malloc(9 * sizeof(struct PVS*)); 
int i; 
for(i = 0; i < 9; i++){
    pvs[i] = (struct PVS*) malloc(9 * sizeof(struct PVS)); 
}

int j,k; 
for(j = 0; j < 9; j++){
    for(k = 0; k < 9; k++){
        int* val = pvs[j][k].values; 
    }
}
```

What would happen if I try and access pvs[j][k]? What type of error will the compiler throw me?

Comment: This program won't compile; you use a type "PVS" without defining it. Please give us real code, and turn on all compiler warnings.

Comment: but i define the structure?

Comment: That's type "struct PVS". There is no type "PVS".

Comment: my bad I fixed the code

Comment: This code creates a 9x9 array of structures with random data, including the pointer "values". If you try to deference that pointer (which you never do in the code given), you invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: What's the actual question? Did you compile it and it gave you errors?

Comment: I know that I dont initialize "values" for each structure. My question is what happens when I try and access "values"?

Comment: @codeLover31 undefined behaviour.

Comment: It depends on what you mean by "access". Printing values, dereferencing pointers for example would be undefined. `int* val = pvs[j][k].values; ` is also undefined.

Comment: Annex J.2 is explicitly telling that any use of indeterminate value of an object with *automatic* storage class is undefined. But it is not telling the same about the dynamically allocated one. So I would say it depends on the future use of it.

Answer (score 0):

No error will occur, but the `values` members are uninitialized, so `val` will have arbitrary contents. You’re invoking so-called undefined behavior (UB). Anything really can happen, and there will be no errors shown – you’ll be lucky to get a crash once you access `val`.

You’d do best to create constructor functions that can construct one PVS, and another that can construct arrays of them, to arbitrary number of dimensions. That way, you’d avoid repeating the same code over and over. You’d be essentially implementing a multidimensional vector container.